# trying to concat two pointer char but one of them is changing

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using Raspberry Pi pico with C. I am trying to take 2 different decimal value to char then concat them. I am taking those decimal values from rfid. The values ​​coming from rfid are not decimal at first, I convert these values ​​to decimal by processing.

```
char *a;
char *b;
a = lltoa(decimal_2, 10);
printf(a);
b = lltoa(decimal, 10);
printf(b);
int newSize = strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1;
char *newBuffer = (char *)malloc(newSize);
printf("\n");
strcpy(newBuffer, a);
strcat(newBuffer, b);
printf(newBuffer);
```

The output is :

```
999210803000150
150210803000150
```

The 999 which is a's value is changing. Why char *a is changing ?

Here is my lltoa function (I took from stack overflow):

```
char *lltoa(long long val, int base)
{

    static char buf[64] = {0};

    int i = 62;
    int sign = (val < 0);
    if (sign)
        val = -val;

    if (val == 0)
        return "0";

    for (; val && i; --i, val /= base)
    {
        buf[i] = "0123456789abcdef"[val % base];
    }

    if (sign)
    {
        buf[i--] = '-';
    }
    return &buf[i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `lltoa` function you have:

```
static char buf[64] = {0};
```

When you define a local variable as `static` it means there's only *one* single instance of the variable, shared between all calls to the function.

So when you call `lltoa(decimal_2, 10)` the contents of `buf` is set up one way. Then in the second call `lltoa(decimal, 10)` you overwrite the contents of `buf`.

And since you only have a single `buf`, both the pointers `a` and `b` will both point to this one single `buf`.

Since you want to be able to handle different bases you can't use the standard `snprintf` as I would otherwise suggest, so my recommendation is that you pass a pointer to a large enough buffer as an argument:

```
char *lltoa(long long val, int base, char *buf, size_t buflen);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems include:

**Only one buffer**

See [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401016/2410359).

**Buffer too small**

When `val == LLONG_MIN` and `base == 2`, expected output needs a buffer of size 66.

**Undefined behavior (UB)**

`val = -val;` is UB `val == LLONG_MIN`.

---

Rather than OP's *Here is my lltoa function (I took from stack overflow)*.

Single buffer [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859192/2410359)

Passed in buffer [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29933810/2410359).